# Azure Logic App Application Insights email failing

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-logic-apps

I'm configuring an Azure Logic App to deliver daily digests from Application Insights.

The query I'm running works fine in the Application Insights Metrics Explorer.

I'm asking the app to deliver the query results as an Html table.

It's failing with the following response:

Headers:

```
{
  "Pragma": "no-cache",
  "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
  "Date": "Thu, 13 Jul 2017 07:33:15 GMT",
  "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
  "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
  "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
  "Content-Length": "2197",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Expires": "-1"
}
```

Body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "\"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DraftClient.Exceptions.FailedToParseDraftQueryResponseException: Failed to convert table (JToken) to Table object ---> System.ArgumentException: Can not convert Null to Int32.\\r\\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)\\r\\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DraftClient.Helpers.DraftResponseParser.ConvertToTable(JToken token)\\r\\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\\r\\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DraftClient.Helpers.DraftResponseParser.ConvertToTable(JToken token)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DraftClient.Helpers.DraftResponseParser.ParseDraftQueryResponse(String draftQueryResponseInJson)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DraftClient.DraftApiClient.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__10.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\\r\\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DraftClient.DraftApiClient.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\\r\\n   at DraftFlowConnector.VisualizeDraftResults.<RunAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\\r\\n   at DraftFlowConnector.VisualizeDraftResults.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\""
  }
}
```

Is this thing something I can fix on my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the failure is associated with an attempt to convert a numeric column (which has empty values) to an 'Int' type.

We'll work on a fix for this, and in the meantime, you can work around this by adding a 'where' statement to your query, that filters out rows containing an empty value in the relevant numeric column(s), something like:

```
| where tostring(columnName) != ""
```

Thanks!